# The event where application.onkey is put

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to disable the shortcut of Ctrl button and I've found `Application.onkeyMethod` but I didn't know where I can put them.

`Application.onkey "^p",""`   works in workbook open event but that doesn't happen to copy shortcut, cut,  and so on.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. If you want to prevent copy you need to add `Application.OnKey "^c", ""` - paste would be `Application.OnKey "^v", ""` - the `^` in the first part stands for the `Control` key - the `p` is the key being pressed along with it.

Comment: Thanks but where I must put them . I mean what is the event that I must put this code in to work ?

Comment: You're fine to put them in the `Workbook_Open()` event in `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: I'm writing up a sub for you - unfortunately it doesn't look like excel will let you just do `Application.OnKey "^", ""` which would completely disable control - you have to walk it through the various keys.

Comment: I try this code in all type of event and  the shortcut still works but ^p .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - You can put this in the `ThisWorkbook` object.

Just paste the whole thing in.

This will go through (almost) every key and block the key's combination with control.

This won't let you open the help menu (`CTRL + F1`), it won't let you select all cells (`CTRL + A`) - it won't let you do (most) anything with the control key.

It's worth noting that this **will not** block things like `CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN` - only things like `CTRL+A`.

It would be relatively trivial to add that functionality if you wanted though - you'd just add additional BlockKey requests for `"^+"` and `"^%"` and `"^+%"` - something like that.

Edit: After writing this, I found similar code from someone else here https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win012.htm

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Call DisableControlKey '<- Use this in production
Call DisableControlKey(True) 'True means show in debug window what was blocked -
End Sub

Sub DisableControlKey(Optional ShowInDebug As Boolean = False)
Dim Arr(), x
Arr = Array("{BS}", "{BREAK}", "{CAPSLOCK}", "{CLEAR}", "{DEL}", "{DOWN}", "{END}", _
            "{ENTER}", "~", "{ESC}", "{HELP}", "{HOME}", "{INSERT}", "{LEFT}", "{NUMLOCK}", _
            "{PGDN}", "{PGUP}", "{RETURN}", "{RIGHT}", "{SCROLLLOCK}", "{TAB}", "{UP}")
'Block all ascii characters from 0 to 127
For x = 0 To 127
    If ShowInDebug Then
        Debug.Print Chr(x) & ": " & BlockKey("^" & Chr(x))
    Else
        BlockKey ("^" & Chr(x))
    End If
Next x
'Block all keys on this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey
For x = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    If ShowInDebug Then
        Debug.Print Arr(x) & ": " & BlockKey("^" & Arr(x))
    Else
        BlockKey ("^" & Chr(x))
    End If
Next x
'Block all function keys
For x = 1 To 15
    If ShowInDebug Then
        Debug.Print "F" & x & ": " & BlockKey("^" & "{F" & x & "}")
    Else
        BlockKey ("^" & "{F" & x & "}")
    End If
Next x
End Sub
Function BlockKey(KeyCombo As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnKey KeyCombo, ""
BlockKey = (Err.Number = 0)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can see what's being blocked in the immediate window:

[image: Output]

In theory, you'd really want to go through these combinations and clean up whatever you don't need for speed's sake - get rid of the for loops and just loop through a large array of whatever `CTRL+` key combinations you want to block.

If you wanted to go completely crazy, you could actually install a low level key hook (this is ridiculous) and block CTRL from external applications too. (**Hint: Don't do this.**)

https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c4829/Managing-LowLevel-Keyboard-Hooks-with-the-Windows-API.htm

Comment: First thank you a million , second I am sorry for not replying  immediately but I stay until Igot chance to try the code in a computer , it works like magic .

Comment: Np - happy to help 